# Avro: How to define Protocol from AVDL?

Tags: idl, avro

The reading od AVPR is easy:

```
Protocol protocol = Protocol.parse(new File("ht-proto.avpr"));
```

But this does not work for IDL files (AVDL).

**How to read the AVDL file so I could accomplish the following task but using AVDL instead of AVPR:**

```
public static void main (String[] args)  {
     Main.class.getResourceAsStream("net/protocol_man.avdl");
     Protocol protocol  =
           Protocol.parse(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("net/protocol_man.avpr"));
                                                   //this doesnt work for AVDL       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with maven. you can add the following plugin.

this will create the java sources and with that you can do pretty much everything.

I mean you can later reference to one of the generated classes For example Event.class

and ask for it's Schema Event.$SCHEMA

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schemas</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>net/protocol_man.avdl</include>
                        </includes>
                        <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```